# How to get all the child elements from a specific div

Tags: jquery, html

I am working with jQuery and I need to get all the child elements from a specific `div`.  Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="div1">

<fieldset>
<table>
<tr>
<td><fieldset><table><tr><td><div class="childclass"> 2</td>
<td><fieldset><table><tr><td><div class="childclass"> 4</td>
<td><fieldset><table><tr><td><div class="childclass"> 3</td>
</tr></table>
</fieldset>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

And here is my code for getting the child elements:

```
function gettingid() {
            $('.div1').children('.childclass').each(function () {
                alert(this.text());
            });
        }
```

There is something wrong, but I don't know what.

Comment: `children` only searches one level down. Use `find`.

Comment: See first paragragh here about children vs find: http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USe [**find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$('.div1').find('.childclass').each(function () {
            alert($(this).text());
        });
```

The `.children()` method differs from `.find()` in that `.children()` only travels a single level down the DOM tree while `.find()` can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

Comment: find goes deep for searching

Comment: Thanks for Reply Anoop joshi

Answer (score 0):

//You can use find as mentioned above. Or other wise this would work i think.

```
<script>

    function gettingid() {
        $('.div1 .childclass').children('.childclass').each(function () {
            alert(this.text());
        });
    }
</script>
```